# Mapping polar coordinates to cube

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, coordinates, trigonometry

I am trying map polar coordinates to points on a cube. I was able to map the front, back, left and right faces of the cube, but I am struggling with the top and bottom. Here is what I have:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts polar coordinates to uv coordinates on a cube.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="p">The polar coordinate; p.x = longitude, p.y = latitude.</param>
/// <param name="face">The face of the cube that p maps to.</param>
/// <returns>The xy coordinate on the cube face.</returns>
private Vector2 PolarToCubeFace(Vector2 p, out CubemapFace face)
{
    face = CubemapFace.Unknown;
    Vector2 result = Vector2.zero;

    float lng = p.x; // East-to-West.
    float lat = p.y; // North-to-South.

    if (lat >= 45 && lat <= 135){ // Front, back, left, or right face.
        face = (lng > 0 && lng <= 90) ? CubemapFace.PositiveZ :
            (lng > 90 && lng <= 180) ? CubemapFace.PositiveX :
            (lng <= -90 && lng > -180) ? CubemapFace.NegativeZ :
            CubemapFace.NegativeX;

        result.y = (lat - 45) / 90f;
        result.x = mod(lng, 90) / 90f;
    }
    else{ // Top or bottom face.
        // Need help here.
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd do this by first mapping from spherical coordinates to a cartesian vector on a sphere:

```
float cos = Mathf.Cos(latitude);
Vector3 v = new Vector3(
              cos * -Mathf.Sin(longitude),
              Mathf.Sin(latitude),
              cos * Mathf.cos(longitude));
```

This particular version puts Longitude zero in middle of the PositiveZ face, but you can change this as needed.

Next, to figure out which cubemap face we're in, we need to check which component of this vector is greatest in absolute value:

```
Vector3 abs = new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(v.x), Mathf.Abs(v.y), Mathf.Abs(v.z));

int greatestIndex = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    if(abs[i] > abs[greatestIndex])
        greatestIndex = i;
```

By dividing by this greatest value, we scale the vector v so that it sits on a unit cube:

```
v /= abs[greatestIndex];
```

Now we just need to read the appropriate components for which face we're on:

```
CubemapFace face;
Vector2 facePos;

switch(greatestIndex)
{
    case 0:
        if(v.x > 0)
        {
            face = CubemapFace.PositiveX;
            facePos.x = v.z;
            facePos.y = v.y;
        }
        else
        {
            face = CubemapFace.NegativeX;
            facePos.x = -v.z;
            facePos.y = v.y;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if(v.y > 0)
        {
            face = CubemapFace.PositiveY;
            facePos.x = -v.x;
            facePos.y = v.z;
        }
        else
        {
            face = CubemapFace.NegativeY;
            facePos.x = -v.x;
            facePos.y = -v.z;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if(v.z > 0)
        {
            face = CubemapFace.PositiveZ;
            facePos.x = -v.x;
            facePos.y = v.y;
        }
        else
        {
            face = CubemapFace.NegativeZ;
            facePos.x = v.x;
            facePos.y = v.y;
        }
        break;
}
```

Here the facePos coordinates are in the range -1...1, with the x coordinate increasing as we move eastward across the four equatorial faces. The top and bottom faces are oriented to align with the PositiveZ face. All this is easy to change if you need a different orientation convention.